# Don't move a UISwitch

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiswitch

I want to change the UISwitch on to off and off to on, but I can't. Created the UISwitch in xib.

```
- (IBAction)switchAction:(id)sender {

    UISwitch *nkswitch = (UISwitch *)sender;
    if (nkswitch.isOn)
        NSLog(@"switchPressed ON");
    else
        NSLog(@"switchPressed OFF");

}
```

Any solution?

[image]

Update

[image]

Comment: Make sure you have connected IBAction to uiswitch, if connected then you have to use IBoutlets.

Comment: How do you created switch?? programmatically or from interface builder??
Set this action to **Value changed** event.

Comment: From interface bulider.

Comment: did u put the breakpoint is it going inside that method?

Comment: In Question code there is `- (IBAction)switchAction:(id)sender`, but in your screenshot this is `- (IBAction)switchAction:(UISwitch *)sender` which is correct?

Comment: Yes, is correct! Already works. Removed the view. Added a new view and UISwitch. Stayed without realizing the problem I had.

Comment: @amit soni I used breakpoints and did not enter the method.

Comment: then check ur xib may be on top of uiswitch is there any another view or something

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think the problem is you are connect wrong Event of UISwitch. check in `Xib` or `storyboard`. it is connect with Event of **ValueChange:** insted of Other like:-

[image]

**Set the UISwitch IBAction Event to UIControlEventValueChanged**

Comment: I added a picture to my question

Comment: this is a xib or storyBoard image that you connect event by drag and drop for set eventof UISwtich we need to connect its event to value change insted of touchUpinside. your action is right but you event is connected wrong UIControlEvent

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing wrong in your code,you need to check your connection again or remove your UISwitch,add new one and reconnect.

Comment: I've done it a few times and still not move. I'll try another view